# Browsersync + Gulp.js live reload at Intellij Idea "update resources" lag

Tags: intellij-idea, gulp, browser-sync, livereload, hot-reload

I use Browsersync + Gulp.js in Idea to hot reload my css styles at web page.
Page reload occures properly. **But** resources served at exploded artifacts are overdue.

My workflow:

- I chage change main.css in idea
- browserSync.reload() cause reload of main.css at web page
- but server returns old version of main.css from exploded artifacts, as resources are not updated in idea.

How to obtain updated actual resources on browserSync.reload?

gulpfile.js

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    watchCssAndRefreshBrowser = function() {
        browserSync.init({
            proxy: "localhost:8080/"
        });
        
        return gulp.watch([
            'main.css'
        ]).on("change", function() {
            browserSync.reload('main.css');
        });
    };

gulp.task('live-reload', function(){
    watchCssAndRefreshBrowser();
});
```

Comment: Have you updated the artifact as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html ?

Comment: @y.bedrov, yes i do. But artifact updated after page reloaded. That is a problem.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? Running "update" should update classes and resources in deployed artifact, so actual code is used. Page should be refreshed afterwards to avoid cache usage.